# What do I do with NSData?

Tags: cocoa, nsdata, sendmail

I am trying to send email programmatically... I have this line of code:

```
_mail.AddAttachmentData(nsd,"text/plain", filePath);
```

and I haven't a clue what goes into NSData... I tried taking the string that I was writing to a file, but apparently that doesn't work either.  I believe it is preventing me from doing a good sendmail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSData is a class type.  See here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html

You'll probably want to construct your NSData object using something like this:

```
NSString *myFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyFile" ofType:@"txt"];  
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:myFilePath];
```

Then pass that in as the NSData object.